Input not displayed inside parent
Take the snippet below:


* {
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  height: 100%;
}

#rightPane {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #303030;
}

#leftPane {
  border: solid 1px red;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
}

input {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  direction: rtl;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
<div id="content">
  <div id="rightPane">Right pane</div>
  <div id="leftPane">
    Left pane
    <input type="range" orient="vertical" />
  </div>
</div>



Output (Chrome):

As you can see, the input is not inside its parent. I have no idea why. This behaves identically in Chrome, Firefox, Konqueror, so it must be the "correct" behavior, however counter-intuitive is may be.
Can someone explain to me why the input, which is position : absolute; right : 0px; laid out at 0px to the right of its grandparent and not of its parent like it always is? How should I write my code so that it's 0px from the right of its parent?
My real layout is substantially more complex than this, with leftPane containing canvases with webGL inside which forces me to compute the pixel size in JavaScript and set it dynamically if I want pixel-perfect rendering, but this toy example behaves the same as my actual layout.

Try adding position: relative; to the #leftPane

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute: "[absolute] The element is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor (if any) or to the initial containing block." - if there are no positioned ancestors, then the initial containing block (the viewport) becomes the reference point.

You need to set position: relative to parent element, read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute

Okay that works and it explains it. As I expected, this is a very counter-intuitive behavior. Thanks for the very fast reply everyone !

Just add position: relative; to the id #leftPane, because you have used position: absolute;, so you need to specify a relative positioning context for it, which is achieved by setting the parent element's position property to relative.


* {
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  height: 100%;
}

#rightPane {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #303030;
}

#leftPane {
  border: solid 1px red;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  direction: rtl;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
<div id="content">
  <div id="rightPane">Right pane</div>
  <div id="leftPane">
    Left pane
    <input type="range" orient="vertical" />
  </div>
</div>




Massive dupe. You could have found one of those and commented and voted to close

Dear, @mplungjan I haven't seen the comment section, and thank you for your suggestion. –

Is there a way to make that question easier to find when, like in my case, you have no idea that "absolute" was the problem ? I did search, but without that knowledge (and therefore, the solution) I had no chance to find that other question.
